# Help with this typerror in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

```
 benfordd = dict()
 for attr in attrs:
      benfordd.setdefault(attr, []).extend([val*1e6 for val in x if not np.isnan(val)])
```

the above is just parts of my code, why is it that when I run this in ipython, I get this:

TypeError: function not supported for these types, and can't coerce safely to supported types.

does anyone know what values are needed for this?  attr are strings.

p.s., what does "val" stand for?

Comment: "val" is short for value. If you want to know what it means in this context, read about list comprehensions: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

I believe this error can occur when using Sage with numpy. The reason is that Sage preparses your input, so that e.g. `0.6**2` is translated to `RealNumber('0.6') ** Integer(2)`. This allows it to handle real numbers with arbitrary precision. Unfortunately, numpy can't handle these, because it doesn't know what a `RealNumber` is.

If you define `RealNumber = float`, the code should work; see [the docs](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/faq/faq-usage.html#i-have-type-issues-using-scipy-cvxopt-or-numpy-from-sage).

Comment: it doesn't work, but thanks for pointign me in that direction, I will look into it.  Let me know if you have any other ideas!  Thanks.